# php Open daily day rage

Tags: php, time

I building restaurant service and currently i'm stuck figuring out how to display open daily restaurant like google Business.

I have table design

```
+-----+----------+------+----------+----------+
| ref | id_resto | day  | open     | close    |
+-----+----------+------+----------+----------+
|   2 |        5 |    1 | 13:00:00 | 21:00:00 |
|   5 |        5 |    2 | 13:00:00 | 21:00:00 |
|   7 |        5 |    3 | 13:00:00 | 21:00:00 |
|   9 |        5 |    4 | 13:00:00 | 21:00:00 |
|  10 |        5 |    6 | 13:00:00 | 22:00:00 |
|  11 |        5 |    7 | 14:00:00 | 21:00:00 |
+-----+----------+------+----------+----------+
```

day 7 = sunday, 1 = monday, 2 = tuesday, 3 = Wednesday and soo on

according to my table it should be display

```
Monday-Thursday 13:00 - 21:00
Saturday 13:00 - 22:00
Sunday 14:00 - 21:00
```

i've try some algorithm, but noting happened -_-
any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Did u try it with Php?

Comment: So you want it to display separate entries for Monday-Thursday, Saturday, and Sunday?

Comment: devpro yes i did, but nothing happen ;(
techdude yap, you're right

Answer (score 0):

With a small change to your table structure, it should be simple to implement.

Here is my code to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `daytype` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `daytype` VALUES (1,'Monday - Thursday'),(2,'Saturday'),(3,'Sunday');

CREATE TABLE `hours` (
  `ref` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_resto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_daytypes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ref`)
);

INSERT INTO `hours` VALUES (2,5,1,'13:00','21:00'),(5,5,2,'13:00','21:00'),(7,5,3,'14:00','21:00');
```

From this you can then easily get the data you want with a simple join:

```
SELECT d.description, CONCAT(open, ' - ', close) as hours FROM test.hours AS h INNER JOIN daytype AS d ON (d.id = h.id_daytypes);
```

Output:

[image: Output containing business hours]

This structure has the added benefit of allowing you to set up different breaks, and different displays for each of the restaurants, if needed. For example, if a restaurant had different hours on Monday, you could add an entry to the daytypes table for Monday, and Tuesday-Thursday.

Overall, this should save some space since you don't need to enter duplicate info for each of the days that are the same.

Hopefully this will help you get started.

UPDATE: Per request, here is an example of how to check if something is open today.

You could have a php function that returns a comma delimited list of all valid daytypes for the current day. Something like this:

```
<?php

/*
1   Monday - Thursday
2   Saturday
3   Sunday
4   Friday
5   Monday
*/

function getDayType()
{
    $dayOfWeek = date('l');
    switch($dayOfWeek)
    {
        case "Monday":
            return "1, 5"
        case "Tuesday":
        case "Wednesday":
        case "Thursday":
            return "1";
        case "Friday":
            return "4":
        case "Saturday":
            return "2";
        case "Sunday":
            return "3"
    }
}
```

Then is is simple to determine the shops that are open today.

For example, like this query which will return all the restaurants that are open.

```
SELECT 
    h.id_resto
FROM
    test.hours AS h
        INNER JOIN
    daytype AS d ON (d.id = h.id_daytypes)
WHERE
    id_daytypes IN (1 , 5)
    AND (
            (HOUR(NOW()) > HOUR(open) AND HOUR(NOW()) < HOUR(close))
        OR 
            (HOUR(NOW()) = HOUR(open) AND MINUTE(NOW()) >= MINUTE(open))
        OR
            (HOUR(NOW()) = HOUR(close) AND MINUTE(NOW()) < MINUTE(close))
    );
```

Comment: if i use this table, how i can display when today is open or not?